# pgbouncer 1.7 with master and slave

Tags: postgresql, master-slave, pgbouncer

I am new in using pgbouncer 1.7 and I want to configure it with master slave configuration.

I have configured postgres 9.3 streaming replication using repmgr and I want to use pgbouncer for load balancing and connection pooling so that it automatically switches to slave if master goes down . So how should I configure it for the same. I have both master and slave on diff servers and og bouncer on diff servers. Do i need to install pgbouncer on both master and slave servers also for it to work or just installing on a diff server will work .

I have tried many online tutorial for it but sadly didnt found any suggestions. Please if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance,
Mohit

Answer (score 1):

**PgBouncer does not have automatic failover**, propagation and ex-master rebuild handling. You can change IP for same hostname to failover though:

https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html

> ## How to failover
>
> PgBouncer does not have internal failover-host configuration nor detection. It is possible via some external tools:
>
> 1. DNS reconfiguration - when ip behind DNS name is reconfigured, pgbouncer will reconnect to new server. This behaviour can be tuned
>    via 2 config parameters - dns_max_ttl tunes lifetime for one hostname,
>    and dns_zone_check_period tunes how often zone SOA will be queried for
>    changes. If zone SOA record has changed, pgbouncer will re-query all
>    hostnames under that zone.
> 2. Write new host to config and let PgBouncer reload it - send SIGHUP or use RELOAD; command on console. PgBouncer will detect changed host
>    config and reconnect to new server.

[Pgpool has automatic failover](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/watchdog_master_slave/en.html) if you wnat to try.